# Can I claim medical expenses credit by amending my previous years' tax returns?

Tags: united-states, healthcare, income-tax

I am filing my taxes very close to the deadline. I was hospitalized for most of last year and had a lot of medical expenses, which way exceed my income. I was wondering if I can claim credit for those excess expenses (expenses - 2010 income) via amending previous year 2009 return? Any clarification here would be greatly appreciated.

thanks much,

Sammy

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Or, perhaps we can safely infer/assume from *"close to the deadline"* that you are in the U.S. i.e. the **April 15th** filing deadline.  Please correct us if we're wrong.

Comment: Yes, in U.S. New York State

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't deduct expenses incurred in 2010 from 2009 income tax.

Source: [IRS publication 502](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p502/ar02.html#en_US_publink1000178852): "You can include only the medical and dental expenses you paid this year."

Sorry. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can amend your return later if you made a mistake (e.g. forgot to take a credit). If you are talking about 2010 and you didn't file the return yet why do you need to amend it? If you can't finish by the deadline file for an extension. For more info see [Extension of Time To File Your Tax Return](http://www.irs.gov/formspubs/article/0,,id=98155,00.html)

Comment: Now that you clarified the question the answer as Joel said below is no, you can't take expenses in 2010 as deduction in 2009 return. Also looks like you can't carry it over into 2011.

Answer (score 1):

April 18, 2011 (not 15th in 2011 due to a holiday) is the tax deadline for Tax Year 2010 (January 2010-December 2010).  Based on your question, it sounds like your medical expenses are for Tax Year 2010.

Your medical expenses for 2010 should be deducted in the taxes you are filing now (April 2011, for tax year 2010).  This is not an amendment or correction to prior year taxes (2009 and earlier).

Comment: I think my question is not clear. The question is if my medical expenses exceed my income, can I claim credit for excess expenses (expenses - last year income) from prior returns 2009 and back?